# Nginx Reverse Proxy wants } at end of htpasswd

Tags: proxy, nginx

After generating the htpasswd file online, nginx gives me the error
"nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/htpasswd:2". The weird thing is, there's only one line. My config file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.html
    auth_basic "User: (username) Password: (password)";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I'm curious as to why this is. Thanks.

Edit: the contents of my htpasswd are as follows:
xxx:$apr1$xxx

Comment: You’re missing a semicolon at the end of the `index` line. That’s probably it.

Comment: @DanielB First, the error was referencing the htpasswd file, and second, adding that didn't do anything.

Comment: Does the file exist at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/htpasswd`? Please include it in your question. You can replace passwords and usernames with `xxx`.

Comment: @DanielB edited.

Answer (score 7):

You placed the htpasswd in the sites-enabled directory of nginx.
In the nginx.conf, there is probably a line like this:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

So all files in that directory are treated as nginx config file.
The content has nothing to do with nginx configuration and therefore you'll get that error.
You need to place that file somewhere else and use the correct path in your auth_basic_user_file option.

Comment: Ah, you genius :)